Circular dependency between the following tasks: :app:generateDebugFeatureTransitiveDeps
I have 3 modules, including:

app
core (android library)
favorite (dynamic feature)

Error like this:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:generateDebugFeatureTransitiveDeps
+--- :app:generateDebugFeatureTransitiveDeps (*)
\--- :favorite:generateDebugFeatureTransitiveDeps
+--- :app:generateDebugFeatureTransitiveDeps (*)
\--- :favorite:generateDebugFeatureTransitiveDeps (*)

Code of build.gradle.kts (module: app)
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}

apply(from = "../shared_dependencies.gradle")

android {
    namespace = "com.piwew.movieapp_cleanarchitecture"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.piwew.movieapp_cleanarchitecture"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    dynamicFeatures += setOf(":favorite")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":favorite"))
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0") // kotlin lang
}

Code of build.gradle.kts (module: core)
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}

apply(from = "../shared_dependencies.gradle")

android {
    namespace = "com.piwew.movieapp_cleanarchitecture.core"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))

    // Kotlin lang
    api("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")

    // Room
    api("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
    api("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")

    // Retrofit library
    api("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    api("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    api("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.11.0")

    // Kotlin coroutine
    api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
    api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1")

    // Android architecture component
    api("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0")
}

code of build.gradle.kts (module: favorite)
plugins {
    id("com.android.dynamic-feature")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

apply(from = "../shared_dependencies.gradle")

android {
    namespace = "com.piwew.movieapp_cleanarchitecture.favorite"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":app"))
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0") // kotlin lang
}

Lastly, shared_dependencies.gradle
dependencies {
    // Glide
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
    ksp("com.github.bumptech.glide:ksp:4.16.0")

    // App compat and UI things
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")

    // Koin DI
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.5.3")
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.5.3")
    implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-android-viewmodel:2.2.3") {
        exclude group: 'io.insert-koin', module: 'koin-android-scope'
    }

    // Navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.7.7")

    // Testing
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}

Help me out if there are any of my dependencies that are wrong causing the error?
I expect no errors when running the application

In your code of build.gradle.kts (module: favorite), you are implementing app module:
    dependencies {
    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":app")) <--- this one
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0") // kotlin lang
}

This is causing the circular dependency
